# Редактор, VS Code как сделать запрет переноса строк jsx?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

При сохранении компонента на react в jsx html разметка переносится неправильно на новые строки, с ошибками как это исправить?
Читал что проблема решается установкой плагина Sublime Babel, но я не могу его найти, помогите пожалуйста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте Prettier - Code formatter и используйте его для форматирования.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. С проблемой разобрался. Помогла смена языкового режима с Java Script на Java Script React, как обычно все оказалось банально просто=)